# TIMESTAMP GROK FAILURE

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

some issue with grok timestamp pattern

```
2020-3-4 10:22:37 >> this will match with this pattern %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:my_time}

2020-3-4 0:2:37 >> this will fail with this pattern %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:my_time}
```

also tried to match the pattern by using this separate pattern like `YEAR MONTH AND DAY` but again it will break when it reaches time `%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}`. Any idea ?

Comment: The issue seems to be with the minutes, the pattern defined in logstash (`(?:[0-5][0-9])`) expects a two digit numbers in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how the minute pattern [is defined](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/1327/patterns/grok-patterns#L59) in logstash: `(?:[0-5][0-9])`. This pattern expects a two digit minute number, which breaks in your second case (`2020-3-4 0:2:37`).

I've changed the pattern to accept a one-digit number of minutes: `(?:[0-5][0-9]|[0-9])`

You can then use this custom pattern:

```
(?<my_time>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?(?:[0-5][0-9]|[0-9])(?::?%{SECOND})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?)
```

which is the `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601` with `MINUTE` replaced by my pattern.

Comment: hI @baudsp, 
It works properly with your modified minutes digits !! i didnt realize that minutes issue !! thankss so much and highly appreciated !!!